How to reboot the Wi-Fi (iwlwifi) on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
When I'm watch videos on YouTube, sometimes I get disconnected due to iwlwifi outage until my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS reboots or do workarounds. Sometimes it just goes out right away after rebooting.
Is there a way to restart my Wi-Fi without rebooting Ubuntu every time?

If one the answers work for you accept the one that worked see https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Hello waltinator, that comment that has a solution didn't work for me but thanks for that comment.


Launch terminal

Copy and paste this answer to terminal
sudo echo Wi-Fi is rebooting &&
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi &&
sleep 10 &&
sudo modprobe iwlwifi &&
sudo echo Wi-Fi established &&
sleep 1 && clear


Enter your password and wait until is finished.


Please be aware it only works on Wi-Fi drivers that are based on proprietary drivers, not additional drivers.
For example: Intel Wi-Fi drivers and Realtek Wi-Fi drivers both are based on proprietary drivers, not additional drivers.

Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of inconveniences by a complete restart of the linux system I've done before.

Hello @kladderradatsch, you're absolutely welcome, this helps only for Wi-Fi drivers that are based on proprietary drivers.

These commands work for me:
nmcli radio wifi off  
nmcli radio wifi on


That's great but to me it doesn't fix it for me, because when I do that, I have to wait for few seconds until the Wi-Fi is re-enabled and it won't connect until reboot Ubuntu, so I have to do a workaround myself. When I did this command for me. sudo echo Wi-Fi is rebooting && sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 10 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo echo Wi-Fi established && sleep 1 && clear It fixes my issues for my Wi-Fi on Ubuntu
